# Maven dependency scope for robolectric either stops tests running or makes build run out of heap space

Tags: android, maven, robolectric

I have this Android project and some difficulty configuring the build with Maven & Robolectric. If I set the scope of the robolectric dependency to 'test', then the project builds fine, but the tests fail to run [wrong version of junit  or java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]. If I don't set the scope of the robolectric dependency, the tests run fine (and pass) but the build runs out of heap space.

I'm new to Maven and am probably doing something wrong.

My dependencies look this ::

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
        <version>4.45</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.45</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.45</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Any wisdom on what's going on here will be gratefully received and put to immediate good use :)

Here's the complete pom.xml after updating with Matt's advice. (below) Unfortunately the issue persists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.odl</groupId>
    <artifactId>GhostRunner</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>GhostRunner</name>

    <properties>
        <platform.version> 2.3.3 </platform.version>
        <android.sdk.path>/Users/chrisdanson/Development/android-sdk-macosx</android.sdk.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-android</artifactId>
            <version>4.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                    </sdk>
                                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So .. having updated the plugin dependency versions and run a mvn 'clean' & 'install' as well the problem is still present. Running a robolectric test gives the following output >>

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 30 more
```

Further investigation >

This [link](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes)  shows jars that contain Opcodes and I've added this dependency I found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm-all/2.2)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I've added this as the first dependency in the pom and I still get NoClassDefFound for OpCodes.

Finally found something that seems to work :: have added `<classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>` to the robolectric dependency and the tests finally run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
    <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-alpha-1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and then

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
    <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I don't believe you can have the same dependency listed twice like that and have the app compile but I may be wrong.

None the less, try updating some of your dependency versions. I'm using junit 4.10 with success, along with robolectric 2.1 (2.0 worked as well when I was using that), then mockito is at 1.9.5 as well.

I recommend checking maven central for latest dependencies. I believe there were issues with jUnit 4.11 and robolectric previously though so I haven't tried to upgrade that to 4.11 yet.

Comment: Thanks Matt hadn't spotted that. I've updated to the dependency versions but I think I may have the order wrong. Any chance you could publish your pom.xml?

Comment: Also you can update maven-compiler-plugin to 3.1 and android-maven plugin to 3.6.0. Also, you should have the scope of test for robolectric, otherwise it will include it with your APK which isn't necessary.  One other thing to note that my project has different is I only depend on mockito-core instead of mockito-all.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed that I've got different is I'm using version 4.1.1.4 for com.google.android.

Comment: Also, make sure you do a clean before you try again (mvn clean install). If none of this works, you might need to put up some of your code and a more detailed error message.

Comment: Cheers Matt .. Much appreciated. will try out your suggestions as soon as I can get my day job out of the way.

Comment: ok -- changed everything you suggested and have posted above the compiler output when running a robolectric test.